# WebdriverIO - How to send arguments to Jasmine tests?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jasmine, webdriver-io

I have a bunch of [Webdriver.io](http://webdriver.io/)/Selenium tests, and I'm using the jasmine test framework to write my tests in, so I have a wdio.conf.js file that I have configured to use jasmine, as per [these instructions](http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/frameworks.html)

The trouble is that I'm testing an ad/marketing based web app that is highly dynamic/configurable, and requires me to pass in a load of configuration information so that the test knows what to test. e.g. at the command line I would like to run something like:

```
> wdio --campaignId=123 --productId=456
```

I can modify the 'onPrepare' function/event in the wdio.conf.js file to pick up these paramters like so:

```
exports.config = {
    ....other options (snip)...

    framework: 'jasmine',

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 9999999,
        expectationResultHandler: function (passed, assertion) { }
    },

    onPrepare: function (config) {
        var campaignId = parseInt(process.argv[2]
            .replace('--campaignId=', ''));
        var productId = parseInt(process.argv[3]
            .replace('--productId=', ''));

        config.params = {
            campaignId: campaignId,
            productId: productId
        };
    }
};
```

...but I have no idea how to pass these along to my jasmine tests. I've tried reading from process.argv but the campaignId and productId args are missing, e.g.

```
describe('Campaign Tests', function () {

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        browser
            .session(function(err, client) {
                var campaignId = parseInt((process.argv[2] || '')
                    .replace('--campaignId=', ''));
                var productId = parseInt((process.argv[3] || '')
                    .replace('--productId=', ''));

                // campaignId and productId are both NaN/undefined
            });
    });

    it('should test something...snip...
```

How do I pass custom params/arguments along to my jasmine tests? I could write them to a file in onPrepare and then read that file in jasmine tests, that seems a bit hacky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend to use environment variables to approach this behavior.

So for example you can run your tests like `VARIABLE=1 wdio wdio.config.js` and then in your test you can access it easily with `process.env.VARIABLE`

If you are using some build tool like gulp, grunt, etc. than you can pass command lines the standard way (`gulp e2e --variable=1`) and then set `process.env.VARIABLE` inside the build tool task.

Comment: Can I add custom variable like process.env.xyz and pass xyz value from CLI?