# How to pass environment value from npm to wdio file

Tags: webdriver-io

I wanted to pass the test environment value from command line with npm command which should be accessible into wdio.conf file. Something like npm test --env='stage'.
How to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is direct way in WDIO to achieve it. The one option that we used is:

Defined the below in the `wdio.conf.js` file:

```
const testEnv = process.env.TEST_ENV || 'FIT'; //code to read the value from cmd
exports.config = { 
.... 

beforeSession: function(){
    global.testEnv = testEnv; //making the testEnv global
}
....
}
```

Command to start the test: `TEST_ENV='stag' npm test`

So in your project the variable `testEnv` would be available throughout.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply!!!
When Intriwd to run test, it gave me following error,
'TEST_ENV' is not recognized as an internal oe external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Following is the entry in package.json
"test": "node ./node_modules/webdriverio/bin/wdio wdio.conf.js"

Comment: try by changing it as `"test": "wdio"`

Comment: here is a nice hint as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153459/webdriverio-how-to-send-arguments-to-jasmine-tests

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
    if (process.argv !== undefined && process.argv.length) {
    process.argv.forEach(arg => {
            if (arg.indexOf('--env=') !== -1) {
                process.env.env = arg.replace('--env=', '');
            }
    });
  }
  console.log("Environment : " +  process.env.env)
},
```